# Youtube iframe is Not Displaying After Re-Opening The Modal using IFrame Player API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a site that loads youtube, html5 video, and vimeo. I ended up having trouble with the Youtube using the API. The video is loaded on a modal.
At first click, the player seems to be working. But after closing and opening it again, the iframe won't load anymore. Here is my code:
HTML:
`<div class="youtube-video video-view" id="R7JnYfAhwXk"></div>`

Script:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var players = {};
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    var yt = $('.youtube-video');
    yt.each(function(){        
        players[$(this).attr('id')] = new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'),
            { 
                videoId: $(this).attr('id'), 
                height: '135',
                width: '249',
                events: { 
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

}
```

See image for additional reference:
[On First Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6m5X.png)
[On Second Click After Closing the Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT9b6.png)

Additional Information:
The modal is removed on close. I tried removing the youtube api on modal close but the issue is still occurring.

```
function hideModal()
{    
    $('.modal.in').remove();
    $( '.modal-backdrop' ).remove();
    $( 'body' ).removeClass( "modal-open" );
    $('html').find('script').filter(function(){
      return $(this).attr('src') === 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
    }).remove();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Remove this `$('html').find('script').filter(function(){
      return $(this).attr('src') === 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
    }).remove();`

Comment: Thanks @darklightcode. I already figured out the best way. I realized there is what we called closures that works.